# Python: double Backslash formatting

Tags: python, backslash

I'm trying to handle a file address within my python program and pass it to MySQL.

I have found out that I need to use raw strings for the address so it gets to MySQL intact.
This works:

```
myFilePath = r"'D:\\folder\\file.csv'"
sqlStatement = r"LOAD data local INFILE %s INTO TABLE test ...);" % (myFilePath)
```

However, I'm creating a GUI and want the pathname to be changable. So I'm trying to convert a normal filepath into the right format, but I can't get it done.

**How can I convert**

```
filePath = "D:\folder\file.csv"
```

**into the exact same format like myFilePath above?**

The best I've come up with so far is

```
myFilePath = r'r"' + "'" + filePath + "'"
```

But I still need to double the existing backslashes, and I can't find any way to do it. I've tried iterating, like this:

```
myFilePath = ""
for i in range(len(filePath)):
    if i == "\\":
        myFilePath += "\\\\"
    else:
        myFilePath += filePath[i]
```

But that doesn't work, probably because of the escape nature of backslashes.
Just using raw string again creates more backslashes than I want, and I'm out of my depth.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using string formatting to create a SQL statement in the first place.  Once you use the db interface the right way, the problem goes away:

```
file_path = r"d:\folder\file.csv"
cursor.execute("LOAD data local INFILE %s INTO TABLE test ...);", file_path)
```

Using string formatting for SQL statements is just opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This is known as [parameterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements)

Comment: The problem is that I want to input the original filePath as a variable, and I can't do r(filePath) etc. But i just found the solution: repr(filePath) does the job perfectly! 
But thank you for your help anyway. :)

Comment: @Lastalda: I think you are confused about some aspect of this.  You don't need r(filePath).  Using parameterization should have fixed this for you.